# More efficient way to calculate the nth term

Tags: python, recursion

I have the recurrence relation : (n-2)a<sub>n</sub> = 2(4n-9)a<sub>n-1</sub> - (15n-38)a<sub>n-2</sub> - 2(2n-5)a<sub>n-3</sub> with initial conditions being a<sub>0</sub> = 0, a<sub>1</sub> = 1 and a<sub>2</sub> = 3. I mainly want to calculate a<sub>n</sub> mod n and <sub>2n</sub> mod n for all odd composite numbers n from 1 up to say 2.5 million.

I have written down a code in Python. Using sympy and memoization, I did the computation for a<sub>n</sub> mod n but it took it more than 2 hours. It got worse when I tried it for a<sub>2n</sub> mod n. One main reason for the slowness is that the recurrence has non-constant coefficients. Are there more efficient codes that I could use? Or would it help to do this on some other language (which preferably should have an in-built function or a function from some package that can be used directly for the primality testing part of the code)?

This is my code.

```
from functools import lru_cache

import sympy

@lru_cache(maxsize = 1000)

def f(n):

    if n==0:

        return 0

    elif n==1:

        return 1

    elif n==2:

        return 3

    else:

        return ((2*((4*n)-9)*f(n-1)) - (((15*n)-38)*f(n-2)) - (2*((2*n)-5)*f(n-3)))//(n-2)

for n in range(1,2500000,2):

    if sympy.isprime(n)==False:

        print(n,f(n)%n)

    if n%10000==1:

        print(n,'check')
```

The last 'if' statement is just to check how much progress is being made.

Comment: I'm not certain, but it seems you might have subscript typos, which make the question rather hard to read.

Comment: Try not to compare to booleans: `if sympy.isprime(n)==False:` should be `if not sympy.isprime(n):`. I also think your cache size is very small given the problem. Unless you have a reason to limit memory usage, trading performance for memory doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I would guess that `isprime` has more computational effort that your function.

Comment: Most people outside India will have no idea what a "lakh" is. Please don't use Indian words here.

Answer (score 1):

For a somewhat faster approach avoiding any memory issues, you could calculate the a<sub>n</sub> directly in sequence, while always retaining only the last three values in a queue:

```py
from collections import deque

a = deque([0, 1, 3])

for n in range(3, 2_500_000):
    a.append(((8 * n - 18) * a[2] 
              - (15 * n - 38) * a[1] 
              - (4 * n - 10) * a.popleft()) 
             // (n - 2))
    if n % 2 == 1:
        print(n, a[2] % n)
```

```
3 2
5 0
7 6
9 7
11 1
[...]
2499989 1
2499991 921156
2499993 1210390
2499995 1460120
2499997 2499996
2499999 1195814
```

This took about 50 minutes on my PC. Note I avoided the `isprime()` call in view of Rodrigo's comment.